# The order of decomposition of matrices

Tags: matrix-decomposition

In QR decomposition of a matrix, Q represents the orthogonal matrix and R represent upper triangular. I was wondering if a matrix could be decomposed into orthogonal and lower triangular and found LQ decomposition. Why is it not QL ? Why is the rotation first?

In general why is QR decomposition not RQ ? Is there any reason for multiplication in that order?